# Implementation of the ideal memory layout in rust

Tags: memory, rust

I'm new to Rust and tried to "translate" a chess engine I made in Python into Rust. Since Rust is a more low-level programming language than Python, I care about the memory layout of my program, but don't know how to write my code to store the chess board as efficient as possible in memory

My first approach was a struct with a 2-dimensional array (8x8) to represent the chess board. The items are structs `Piece`, which contaions information about the piece-type (enum) and the color (enum). My code for this is:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum PieceTypes{
    Pawn,
    Knight,
    Bishop,
    Rook,
    Queen,
    King,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Colors{
    White,
    Black,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Piece{
    pub piece_typ: PieceTypes,
    pub color:Colors,
}

pub struct Board{
    pub squares:[[Option<Piece>; 8]; 8],
}
```

But the size of an initialized `Board`-Struct in memory is 128 bytes. 16 bytes per row, 2 bytes per square.This is, of course, perfetly fine, but 8 different pieces with 2 different colors (16 possibilities) definitely don't require 2 bytes (65536 possibilities). Probably this is because the piece type and the color are stored in seperate bytes.

As the beginner I am I wonder how to layout my code so one square uses one byte in memory (Also: Because I am, as mentioned, quite a noob in Rust, explicit code examples would be really helpful)

Comment: [packed_struct](https://docs.rs/packed_struct/latest/packed_struct/) might prove useful to cram all your data into 1 byte.

Comment: Tip: It should probably be `PieceType` as it's not more than one type at once. Likewise `Color` as in `Piece(PieceType,Color)`. You could also have `enum Piece` be `White(PieceType), Black(PieceType), None`.

Comment: Unless you're on a super memory constrained device, it's best not to worry about this unless you have a *measurable* memory problem. Here the difference between 128 bytes and 1 byte is effectively inconsequential as the smallest allocation unit from your operating system is surely far larger than that, likely 4096 bytes or more.

Comment: Crate `bitflags` can also be useful, with an underlying `u8` type.

Comment: If you do want to cram this down as an academic problem to solve, consider one byte per square, and use *bitflags*. There are only 6 pieces, so you need at most 3 bits for that, plus one bit for color. You could reserve all zeroes as "empty", too. Technically this could crunch down to two squares per byte, but then it makes access a lot trickier. Remember, "ideal" has trade-offs. Size comes at the cost of complexity.

Comment: Following up on @tadman's point, if your goal is to optimize memory usage, something to consider is that bit-packing your board state probably will come at the expense of increasing the complexity of your logic (and therefore likely increase the size of your code). Unless you plan on keeping a large number of board states in memory, over-optimizing the size of your state representation might actually **increase** your program's overall memory usage. Always a good idea to measure before and after you optimize!

Answer (score 1):

You can use my library [superbitty](https://docs.rs/superbitty) instead of manual bitfields:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, superbitty::BitFieldCompatible)]
pub enum PieceTypes {
    None,
    Pawn,
    Knight,
    Bishop,
    Rook,
    Queen,
    King,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, superbitty::BitFieldCompatible)]
pub enum Colors {
    White,
    Black,
}


superbitty::bitfields! {
    #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
    pub struct Piece : u8 {
        pub piece_typ: PieceTypes,
        pub color: Colors,
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Board {
    pub squares: [[Piece; 8]; 8],
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<Board>(), 64);

    let mut board = Board { squares: [[Piece::new(PieceTypes::None, Colors::White); 8]; 8] };

    board.squares[0][0].set_piece_typ(PieceTypes::Queen);

    board.squares[0][1] = Piece::new(PieceTypes::King, Colors::Black);
    dbg!(board.squares[0][1].piece_typ(), board.squares[0][1].color());

    dbg!(board);
}
```

However, I'd recommend you to not bother, unless you benchmarked and can prove a performance gain. This can actually hurt your performance.